# How do I remove the concept of auto page breaks from a Microsoft Word Document?

Tags: microsoft-word

I use Microsoft Word just to create notes and I don't need to print these notes. Hence I don't need auto page breaks at all.

I have already set Microsoft Word to remove the spaces between two auto page breaks.

Comment: Word doesn't insert any kind of "auto page breaks". If you want to change the view so that you don't see page formatting then you can simply switch to [draft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/919599/how-to-change-the-default-view-to-draft-view-in-word) or outline view.

Comment: @Mokubai : the problem with the Draft-View is, that my inserted pictures disappear. This makes me not to use the Draft-View to solve my original problem.

Comment: Word is designed for sophisticated word processing tasks; to produce complicated documents that will be printed.  If you just want simple notes and pictures on a continuous, endless page, Word isn't really the best tool for the job.  Depending on the purpose you use it for, you might be working less efficiently than you could be (e.g., it's hard to find things on an endless page unless there's some form of structure).  There are lots of simple editors and note takers designed for the purpose.  Instead of wrestling with Word, consider looking at apps that do exactly what you want.

Comment: If you have MS Office, you should check out OneNote. It sounds like that would serve your needs better than Word.